# Change tax in magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, database, tax, sql, zend-framework

I use magento 2.2.3 with few thousand products.
How to update tax id for all my products with a sql query?

Our products have no product tax. I just wanna add product tax to all products (19%).

Comment: use update attribute from mass action

Answer (score 0):

create a tax class id and attach that to all product using mass action of product grid and then select update attribute to change attribute for all products

Comment: will not work, because i have more then 50.000 products

Comment: then you can use product import/ export feature and add tax class id to the export csv. Only keep sku and tax class in csv and import the products

Comment: start it. Upload is working and i see a please wait graphic since 40 minutes (50.000 products). I hope it's running in background... :-)

Comment: import is done. In admin product detail page the tax is updated correct. I reindex, clean and flush cache. But frontend product detail page the the tax is not shown

Comment: tax will not show on frontend for product details page

Comment: You need to change settings from store-> configurations regarding how you want to show and apply tax over products and cart.
And please accept my answer if it worked for you